# Can't correct my high-low number game in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code for a number game, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but whenever I run it tells me that I'm too low no matter what number I pick. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! Also, I know some of the parts may be redundant, but I don't know if they are actually stopping the code from working.

```
import random
print("Welcome, to the worst game you will ever play. For some reason, you've got to pick a number between 1 and 10. "
      "Pick 11, I dare you.")
print("The aim is to win with the lowest possible score.")
score = 0
player_attempts = 0
play = True

while play:
    computer_number = random.randint(1, 11)
    player_number = int(input("OK. What do you think the number is?"))
    player_number = int(player_number)

    while player_number != computer_number:

        if player_number == computer_number and player_attempts == 0:
                print("Wow. You actually did it. And it only took you " + 
                      str(player_attempts) + "try. I'm impressed. I thought you were just one of those weirdos who "
                      "downloads a dodgy free game to escape from society...")
                score += 1
                player_attempts += 1
                print("Your score is " + str(score) + ". Maybe. I could be lying. How would you know?")
                play = False

        elif int(player_number) == int(computer_number) and int(player_attempts) >= 0:
                    print("Wow. You actually did it. And it only took you " + str(player_attempts) +
                          "tries. I'm impressed. I thought you were just one of those weirdos who "
                          "downloads a dodgy free game to escape from society...")
                    score += 1
                    player_attempts += 1
                    print("Your score was " + str(score) + ". Maybe. I could be lying. How would you know?")
                    play = False

        elif int(player_number) > int(computer_number):
            print("You overshot. But really, does it matter? You should stop, get out of the basement, enter society. "
                  "Or have another go.")
            score += 1
            player_attempts += 1
            print("Your score is " + str(score) + ".")
            again = str(input("Try again."))
            if again == "no":
                play = False
            elif again == "yes":
                play = True

        elif int(player_number) < int(computer_number):
            print("You were too low. Underachieving. Sound familiar?")
            score += 1
            player_attempts += 1
            print("Your score is " + str(score) + ".")
            again = str(input("Try again."))
            if again == "no":
                play = False
            elif again == "yes":
                play = True

        elif int(player_number) == 11:
            print("Wow. You really chose 11. You are actually more intelligent than I had originally thought...")
            again = str(input("Try again."))
            if again == "no":
                play = False
            elif again == "yes":
                play = True
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, it tells me I'm too high.

Comment: I tried your code, it always says I overshot

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I only get overshot when I try to run your code.

Comment: OK, it's now doing the same for me... anyone know why?

Comment: Sounds like he structured his question incorrectly. Since you guys are already running the code, care to tell me what the problem is pleeeaaase :)? I'm just curious and couldn't see the issue in a cursory scan.

Comment: Update: That said, I do wonder if the cast is failing when he's fetching the input. Leading to unexpected comparisons.

Comment: You never leave the inner loop. `player_number` can only be changed in the outer loop. This is covered up by your "Try again" question, where most people assume, they should enter the next number.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed was this

```
    while player_number != computer_number:

         if player_number == computer_number and player_attempts == 0:
            print("Wow. You actually did it. And it only took you " + 
                  str(player_attempts) + "try. I'm impressed. I thought you were just one of those weirdos who "
                  "downloads a dodgy free game to escape from society...")
            score += 1
            player_attempts += 1
            print("Your score is " + str(score) + ". Maybe. I could be lying. How would you know?")
            play = False

         elif int(player_number) == int(computer_number) and int(player_attempts) >= 0:
                print("Wow. You actually did it. And it only took you " + str(player_attempts) +
                      "tries. I'm impressed. I thought you were just one of those weirdos who "
                      "downloads a dodgy free game to escape from society...")
                score += 1
                player_attempts += 1
                print("Your score was " + str(score) + ". Maybe. I could be lying. How would you know?")
                play = False
```

Because the first two if statement will never execute since `while player_number != computer_number:` contradicts the first two conditionals.

Comment: Nice catch.. Totally missed that. *face-palm*

Comment: @iHazCode no worries having a fresh pair of eyes look over your code never hurt anyone :)

Comment: Not my code, just curious to see what's going on here since it didn't jump out immediately for me when I scanned it. In any case, thank you :)

Comment: thanks man - just to clarify, how do you recommend I amend this code? @NathanPatnam

Comment: @NathanPatnam Nevermind, just had another look and saw what you meant - thanks a million mate, I can't believe I never saw that :)

Answer (score 0):

For a computer, it is impossible to generate truly random numbers. Instead we use a method called **seeding** to feed a constantly changing value (such as the current time) to a random number generator, so that it returns different values every time.

Modify your `while` loop to seed the `random` generator object, like so:

```
while play:
    random.seed()
    # This seeds the random number generator with the system time.
    computer_number = random.randint(1, 11)
    player_number = int(input("OK. What do you think the number is?"))
    ...
```

This should initialize the `random` object with the system time so that each execution of the code results in a different and pseudo-random value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure looks like this

```
while play:
    computer_number = randomnumber
    player_number = inputnumber

    while player_number != computer_number:    #not equal
        if condition1:
            congratulation
        elif condition2:
            be sarcastic
        elif condition3:
            be even more sarcastic
```

Now if you guess the number right away, you avoid the inner `while` loop and go to the next computer generated random number. But if you choose a number different from the computer, you enter the inner loop and you are trapped there forever, because you don't change `player_number` or `computer_number`. The solution? Get rid of the inner loop. It is totally unnecessary, because you check this condition with your if-elif construct.

On a side note: The assigned variable of `input()` is already a string variable, no need to convert it with `str(input()`. And if you convert the input with `int(input())` into an integer, then you don't have to do this integer conversion later over and over again, when you call this integer variable.